# Map is not a function while using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm building notes app using react hooks. I use 1 hooks to save data from 2 inputs:

```
const saveNotes = (title, content) => {
const trimmedTitle = title.trim(),
  trimmedContent = content.trim();

setNotes([
  ...notes,
  {
    title: trimmedTitle,
    content: trimmedContent
  }
])};
```

Then I'm trying to map notes like that:

```
 {notes.map((note, index) => (
    <StyledListElement key={index}>
      <Card style={{ margin: "20px", width: "100%" }} variant="outlined">
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h4">{note.title}</Typography>
          <StyledContent>{note.content}</StyledContent>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
            color="secondary"
            onClick={deleteNote}
          >
            Delete note
          </Button>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
```

After that i got an error which says notes.map is not a function. How can I fix this?

Comment: You haven't declared `notes` anywhere.

Comment: I did in my arrow function as a argument ({notes})

Comment: `notes` is not an array. That's why you're getting this error. Run a `console.log(notes)` and see for yourself.

Comment: Not going to argue with you but I stand by my assertion that `notes` isn’t declared anywhere in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, `notes` is not declared using the `useState` hook. Even if exists, ensure to initialize the value correctly before call to the `map` method.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [notes, setNodes] = useState([]); // Initialize as an array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
notes.map && notes.map((note, index)
```

This should work